# List classes in python file

Tags: python

Is there a way to get a list of all classes defined in a file?

for example:
my_classes.py

```
class A:
  pass

class B:
  pass

class C:
```

main.py

```
import my_classes
classes(my_classes)
```

with some kind of result:

```
[<classObject A>, <classObject B>, <classObject C>]
```

Comment: You can use `dir(my_classes)` to get a list of names defined in the module, and you can examine each one to see which are classes.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What specific problem have you encountered and need help with? Do you want all classes in the file, or all classes *defined* in the file? What about nested classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try that:

```
def classes(module):
    for item in module.__dict__.values():
        if isinstance(item, type):
            yield item
```

It depends on the fact that classes are actually instances of `type`.

Answer (score 1):

You may import the module first, and then use:

```
import myfile
dir(myfile)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import mymodule

klasses = []
for objname in dir(mymodule):
    obj = getattr(mymodule, objname)
    if isinstance(obj, (type,)):
        klasses.append(obj)
        print(obj.__name__)
```

Comment: Hello! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Happy to provide more detail for a specific aspect of the code if you have one?